# Will my Lenovo fingerprint scanner work on Windows 7 Professional

Tags: windows-7, fingerprint

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Anyone using the ThinkPad fingerprint reader?](https://superuser.com/questions/41950/anyone-using-the-thinkpad-fingerprint-reader)

I recently purchased Windows 7 but haven't installed it yet. I plan to do a clean install over my current Vista Ultimate. My IBM Lenovo T61 has a fingerprint scanner on the shell, so on the Windows logon screen I can enter my user/pass or just scan my finger. I'm wondering if this will also still work when I installed Windows 7 Professional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. See the answers to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/41950/anyone-using-the-thinkpad-fingerprint-reader/41952)

Comment: Thanks! I did search for a previous answer but obviously my keywords weren't that good.

Comment: No worries.  I only knew how to find that question because I provided an answer to it.  Happy Thanksgiving!